# Import module globally in project

Tags: python, buildout

I have a project built with buildout where I have some development eggs in the src folder with custom namespace and names (Eg. namespace.app1, namespace.app2 etc...).

The code of one of these applications is taken from an existing project and all the imports inside this module are relative (Eg. import appmodule). This imports are no longer working inside my project because I need to use something like

```
import namespace.appname.appmodule
```

How can I import namespace.appname globally in my project to avoid to modify each import that already exists in the code?

Comment: Don't do it, it makes it hard for somebody else to understand what you are doing in your code if you use a module without obvious import. If you really want to do it still: I know that it is possible, but not how. There is a module which globally registers the single underscore as translation function.

Comment: Unfortunately the module is really huge, parsing it to modify each import would take too much time. By now it seems to be the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add the directory of `appmodule` to your `PYTHONPATH` in `~/.profile`,

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:the_directory_of_appmodule
```

and then make it effective by `source ~/.profile`.